# How to get number of googleplus page followers?

Tags: google-plus

is there actually a possibility to get the number of followers of my googleplus-page. the following script - which I found here in an earlier post - doesn't work (no output):

```
$google_api_key = 'XYZXYZXYZXYZXYZXYZ';
$page_id = 'MYNUMERICPAGEID';
$data = @file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/$page_id?key=$google_api_key");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo $data['plusOneCount'];
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a few things wrong:

- Don't have an updated project on the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- Didn't enable the API for that project.
- Are past thresholds/quotas.

Try the following:

1. Login to your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. You'll need a project.

   - If you don't have a project, create one.
3. Enable "Google Plus API" on that project.
4. Confirm usage/quotes are within tolerance and you haven't gone past.

From there, your call should work as normal:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{USER_ID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In my case, I'm querying [Google's](https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550)'s page, so `{USER_ID} = 116899029375914044550`. I can then see the `plusOneCount`:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/bTf-sq_Sg3fLAFijixPfjtKM5f8\"",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://www.google.com",
   "type": "website",
   "label": "www.google.com"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.google.com/support/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Google Help"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://googleblog.blogspot.com/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Official Blog"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://twitter.com/#!/google",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "@google"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.google.com/about/corporate/company/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "Company Info"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.google.com/press/",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "News"
  },
  {
   "value": "http://www.google.com/press/google-directory.html",
   "type": "other",
   "label": "More Google pages"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "page",
 "id": "116899029375914044550",
 "displayName": "Google",
 "tagline": "News and updates on Google's products, technology and more",
 "aboutMe": "<p>Welcome to Google&#39;s official page. Here, you&#39;ll find product news and announcements, company updates, glimpses into what it&#39;s like to work at Google, discussions on technology and the web, and much more. </p><p><span>Given the volume of feedback we receive here, we may not be able to respond individually to every comment and we&#39;re not able to provide product support (if you&#39;re having product issues, please visit our Help Center). Rest assured we&#39;re paying attention, and we&#39;re always eager to hear from you.</span></p>",
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/+google",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAC9wQ/JD8tdz3bFTM/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "plusOneCount": 10757884,
 "circledByCount": 7692912,
 "verified": true,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PLPoXvnN0XI/UTdr4xTtuHI/AAAAAAAA_1U/p1n_Za3BZUg/s630-fcrop64=1,00000000fe06fe97/g_plus_background.png",
   "height": 528,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": 0,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after activating the PlusAPI the script works!

BUT it doesnt show the number of followers but rather the number of +1. What to do for the number of page followers?

Comment: Probably (guessing) want the `circledByCount`.